# Time Machine: Include files and folders from another drive

Tags: time-machine

Is there a way to **include** folders and files to a Time Machine backup, say, because they are on another drive?

I am using Yosemite version 10.10.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up Time Machine the first time, it automatically excludes any external drives including the Time Machine drive itself.

If you want to have certain drives included, just remove them from the exclusion list inside `System Preferences > Time Machine > Options` and they are backed up the next time Time Machine runs.

For more information, check out Apple's official support document: [Mac Basics: Time Machine backs up your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250)